# How to get the console output of an added BrowserView in electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I dynamically created a `BrowserView` in the renderer process. To be more specific, when a button is clicked, the following function is invoked to create and show the `BrowserView`:

```js
const showBrowserView = async () => {
    const view = new remote.BrowserView();
    remote.getCurrentWindow().addBrowserView(view);
    view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000 });
    view.setAutoResize({ width: true, height: true })
    await view.webContents.loadURL(`https://www.google.com`);
}
```

My question is, is there any way to see the console output of this `BrowserView`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the dev tools of the particular browser view you could use

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsopendevtoolsoptions

Or if you want to get the console out put events, you could use

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-console-message

Both these are available through the webcontent object.